# sqlite3 - specify insert pattern

Tags: sqlite

I want to assure a column of my table in `sqlite3` to be a text by `CREATE TABLE` directly from the command line, which has following form: `ABCD-1234`. The first part should consist of only characters, then comes a minus sign `-`, then comes the second part which should be `INT`. Is there anyway to do that?

I tried to create a table with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE test(ID int check(typeof(ID) = 'integer'), Des text check(Des like '%-%'));
```

But it also accepts following unwanted records:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES(1, 'abc-def');
INSERT INTO test VALUES(2, '123-456');
```

Comment: I might consider handling this in the app layer.  What language are you using?

Comment: Yes, I knew it. The question is if it could be done directly in command line.